# charger disconnects and reconnects at 100%

Tags: power-management, battery

I have recently installed ubuntu (22.04) on an Asus ExpertBook B5. Overall things work great. However, when the laptop reaches 100% charge, the charger acts as though it has been unpluggged, making the sound that happens when you disconnect it. Then, almost immediately, it reconnects and makes the sound that happens when you plug it in. This then repeats seemingly indefinitely.

I unplugged the laptop for a minute or so and then plugged it back in and now it seems stable at 100% charge and connected to power. However, I have run into the issue multiple times when the laptop charges from <100% to 100%.

I have very little idea how to debug this issue, so any advice would be appreciated. I am using the OEM USB C charger.

[image]